# How to read values from Excel using Openrowset Function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, openrowset

I am reading excel sheet using openrowset function?

My Excel sheet has numeric value in General Type Column. For some reason these values are brought over as nulls even though they have a values.  I am not sure why this is happening.  I looked into the format of the fields and they are set to General in Excel, I tried setting them to Text and that did not help.

I tried to bring the contents from the excel source to a text file in csv format and for some reason the Text field containing numeric value came out as blank (NULL).

Any inputs on getting this addressed will be much appreciated.

```
SET @Cmd = 'INSERT INTO Table_01
                SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'', ''Excel 8.0;Database=' + @ExcelFilePath + ''',
                ''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'')'
    EXEC(@Cmd)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to do with TypeGuessRows and IMEX:

```
OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;Database=x.xls',
'SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$]');
```

TypeGuesssRows can be found at:

```
HKEY_Local_Machine/Software/Microsoft/Jet/4.0/Engines/Excel/
```

A value of 0 means all rows.

Comment: I set the value to 0 and it read all numeric values but now ingoring AlphaNumeric values from the same column. Actually column has alphanumeric, numeric only and alphabets only. What do you suggest here?

Comment: This is when you have IMEX=1 ? I have tried this with very mixed data and SQL Server 2008, and it works for me.

Comment: Thanks Its worked for me as well. Earlier I didn't try with IMEX=1. Thanks again.